# Repeating loop using for condition

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-controls

```
<li style="width: 20%">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="width: 200px">
                <div class="fader">
                    <img src="./Images/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                    <p align="center">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" ID="lnk" Text="View" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

If i want to repeat list 12 times using for loop or some other looping condition.

Can you help how to solve !!

Comment: What is your server side language?
You may use PHP, ASPX, etc.

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of server-side emitter of javascript to do this.

Comment: ASP.NET from the look of it

Comment: Use JavaScript, Twig... What language do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ASP.NET and you want to display server-side controls  (asp:Button) you can't simple construct your HTML as string and output it to the page.

Define your UL/OL tag with `runat = "server"` attribute, so it is accessible in server-side code.

```
<ul id="myList" runat="server" ></ul>
```

Then add LI and the rest of them as child Controls of the original element.

```
Dim li As HtmlGenericControl

For I = 1 To 12

    li = New HtmlGenericControl("li")
    li.Style("width") = "width: 20%"

    myList.Controls.Add(li)

Next
```

The VB.NET example above builds UL with 12 LI elements. Similarly an LI element has `.Controls` property of it's own to which you can add other controls (DIV etc.)

Comment: what about the button and image?

Comment: @christiandev *Similarly an LI element has .Controls property of it's own to which you can add other controls (DIV etc.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `asp:repeater` for this type of scenario if using `webforms`

[using a repeater](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/repeater-control-example-in-aspnet.html)

[Bind repeater to generic list](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=322)